# webservice call using Post

Tags: java, ajax, web-services, class, post

I am new to webservice and ajax .. I tried to call a webservice using POST method.
I tried to invoke it using Postman (Google chrome App) and I was getting the response but when I tried using Ajax  I am getting error
Following are the things I did:

My Code: (I wrote a JS in which I included following code and tried all the commented options too ):

```
$.ajax({
    crossDomain: true,
    url : 'https://yxyxyxyxyx/search/v1/query.json', 
    type : 'POST',
    dataType : "json",
    data: {appId: "a9b475a079",query: "dhcp"},
    //async : true,
    //headers: {"Content-type": "application/json"},
    headers: { 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*' },
    //contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    //headers: ('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS'),
    //headers: ('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization, X-Request-With'),
    //headers: ('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true'),
    // Access-Control-Allow-Origin: "http://localhost:8080",
    // headers: { 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*' },
    //userAgent : 'Mozilla/22.0',

    success: function(data){

     alert("hi success");
    },
    error: function(data) {alert("An error occured: " + data.status + " " + data.statusText);
    });
```

I am getting the alert in the error and getting following error while debugging:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://www.sample.search/v1/query.json. The request was redirected to 'https://www.sample/obrareq.cgi?wh%3DCCI-STG4%20wu%3D%2Fuesps%…n-tools-stage.cisco.com%20ru%3D%252Fuesps%252Fsearch%252Fv1%252Fquery.json', which is disallowed for cross-origin requests that require preflight.
```

I tried all the options to resolve the CROS option in which I found on net… do we have any other way to resolve it.

Can someone help me if we can do it using a java class that will also serve the purpose

Comment: **Have you skipped the url?** from authentication because if not your _filters_ if any will try to redirect your traffic to authentication page

Comment: Looks like a CORS problem - what domain are you serving the JS from? the same domain that you are attempting to access (your javascript file has to come from the same URL as the AJAX is going to or you have to enable CORS)? I can't tell if the url is www.sample.search, www.sample or yxyxyxyxyx (maybe you are serving it locally?)